A secure way to store SSH credentials (MAUI / C# application)
I currently use Preferences to save all the other data I reuse in my application. So, when it comes to SSH credentials, host/port/username can be stored in plain-text, but what to do with the password?
        Preferences.Default.Set("hostname", entryHostname.Text);
        Preferences.Default.Set("port", int.Parse(entryPort.Text));
        Preferences.Default.Set("username", entryUsername.Text);

Can it be encrypted and stored as a string or a byte array?
Maybe serialize a ConnectionInfo object and save it as .json file?
What are the other options? How do the other applications store credentials in a secure way?

JuiceSSH or Raspicast as references


Here is what Raspicast does with the SSH passwords:
https://github.com/HaarigerHarald/raspicast/blob/3395f68a969376afba44ece3e4c9b2932c485c6b/src/main/java/at/huber/raspicast/utils/PasswordEncrypter.java

The first step when it comes to security is generally to establish trust boundaries and the threat context. Without these the rest is completely pointless. So against whom and what kind of threats do you want to protect yourself with encryption?

Are keys an option?

@Voo it's only a small pet project of mine, so no real threats involved. I'm researching the question since it's my first time encountering a problem of credentials storing. I'm currently reviewing several open-source projects trying to understand and maybe emulate their approach.

@JimRedmond I'll look into keys too. I'd like to offer users a choice of both key/passphrase and username/password options. Something like JuiceSSH or Raspicast (see screenshots in the post). The question is — how to store the credentials so that the user doesn't have to retype password every time the app is relaunched.

Both Preferences and Secure storage could achieve the same result.
And SecureStorage uses the Preferences API and follows the same data persistence outlined in the Preferences documentation.
However, data of SecureStorage is encrypted with the Android EncryptedSharedPreferences class, from the Android Security library, which wraps the SharedPreferences class and automatically encrypts keys and values.
So when it comes to security, SecureStorage is safer than Preferences.
For more information, you can check document Platform differences of SecureStorage and Limitations.

Thanks for your advice! I was on the right track with Preferences, it seems. I'll look into SecureStorage functionality.

There's no 100% secure way to store the important credentials locally without the risk of being compromised. Even if you try to encrypt the values, as long as it is done in the application and is a part of your app's code, it's not completely safe. You could try storing the important data in the cloud, and temporarily loading them in memory for usage, but this possibility depends on your application's context.
Also, the OS matters too. In Android and iOS, it's generally harder to extract apps saved data using applications or tools from outside.

I'm not looking for a 100 % secure solution, I'm just researching the question since it's my first time encountering a problem of credentials storing. I'm currently reviewing several open-source projects trying to understand and maybe emulate their approach.
